# c3.js Bar Chart: how to display data labels diagonally

Tags: c3.js

I'm using c3.js Bar Chart in my React Project, I want to display the data labels diagonally, how can I achieve this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJESQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `axis.x.tick.rotate`. I think `axis.x.height` needs to be also specified.

[C3js Example](https://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_rotate.html)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I'm looking.

Comment: @Jasper Ejoc if it will work for you, please consider tagging the answer as accepted.